# How to get item with max id?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm tryig to get the ítem with max id using this query

```
realm.objects(Entity).filter("@max.id").first
```

It's throwing an error saying that can't parse query so it seems this is not the correct way to do it.

How can I write this query on Realm for Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filters alone cannot do what you're after as they only consider a single top-level object at a time.

Beyond that conceptual issue, there are a few issues with the code you posted:

1. `@"@max.id"` is not a valid [`NSPredicate` format string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795). `NSPredicate` format strings must be composed of comparisons between expressions, not expressions on their own.
2. Collection operators such as `@max` must be applied to a collection. In your example it is being applied to an `Entity`. Since an `Entity` is not a collection, the predicate would not be valid. It would be valid to apply a collection operator to a `List` property on `Entity` though.

Something like the following should do what you're after:

```
let entities = realm.objects(Entity)
let id = entities.max("id") as Int?
let entity = id != nil ? entities.filter("id == %@", id!).first : nil
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! I wonder if there is a serious performance penalty when loading all elements from database (in case there is a considerable nunmber) just to find greatest id

Comment: Realm's queries are lazy, so only a single `Entity` object will be loaded by this approach.

Comment: I'm actually getting this error when trying your code (sorry, I wasn't able to test it until  now but looked very solid).  `Argument for generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred`. It seems to be related with `max` method

Comment: The code snippet was typed from memory. I've updated it to include the cast that's necessary for Swift to determine the return type of the call to `max`. I've also updated it to gracefully handle the case where there are no existing `Entity` instances.

Comment: Now we have a winner. Thanks!

Comment: @bdash are you used this predicate in objective c because i am used in iOS objective c if you known objective c realm please replay me.....

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0

Following worked for me:

```
let allEntries = realm.objects(Model.self)
if allEntries.count > 0 {
    let lastId = allEntries.max(ofProperty: "id") as Int?
    return lastId! + 1
} else {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 and Xcode 9.3**

```
if let personWithMaxAge = realm.objects(Person.self).max(by: { $0.age > $1.age }) {
    print(personWithMaxAge.age)
}
```