# realmswift : manipulate arrays with realm object

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

I am stucked with a problem in my app development.

I have 2 objects, car and Conso.

Conso :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class Car : Object {

    //@objc dynamic var ID = 0
    @objc dynamic var idCar = ""
    @objc dynamic var creadtedAt = NSDate()
    @objc dynamic var modifiedAt = NSDate()
    @objc dynamic var marque = ""
    @objc dynamic var modele = ""
    @objc dynamic var immatriculation = ""
    @objc dynamic var couleur = ""
    @objc dynamic var pseudo = ""
    @objc dynamic var kilometrage = ""
    @objc dynamic var commentaire = "j"
    @objc dynamic var reservoir = ""
    @objc dynamic var dateImmat = ""
    @objc dynamic var motorisation = ""
    @objc dynamic var dateAchat = Date()
    @objc dynamic var numeroSerie = ""
    @objc dynamic var pressionPneu = ""
    @objc dynamic var data: NSData?

}
```

and Car :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class Conso : Object {

    //var id: Int
    @objc dynamic var idConso: String?
    @objc dynamic var dateConso = Date()
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    @objc dynamic var carName: String?
    @objc dynamic var carKilometrage: String?
    @objc dynamic var carKmParcourus: String?
    @objc dynamic var nomStation: String?
    @objc dynamic var adresseStation: String?
    @objc dynamic var CPStation: String?
    @objc dynamic var villeStation: String?
    @objc dynamic var typeCarburant: String?
    @objc dynamic var conso: String?
    @objc dynamic var volConso: String?
    @objc dynamic var prix: String?
    @objc dynamic var coutLitre: String?
    @objc dynamic var commentaire: String?
    @objc dynamic var data: NSData?

}
```

Conso is an object which depends on car, so carName is part of Conso object.

Now I want to display for each car the maximum "Kilométrage"

So In my tableView, I put this code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tdbCarCell", for: indexPath) as! tdbCarsTableViewCell
    print("tableView -> cellForRowAt")
    // Configure the cell...
    let modele = self.carObjects[indexPath.row].modele
    let pseudo = self.carObjects[indexPath.row].pseudo
    let km = self.carObjects[indexPath.row].kilometrage

    let consoData = realm.objects(Conso.self).filter("carName = '" + pseudo + "'")
    cell.labelCarPseudo?.text = pseudo
    cell.labelCarModele?.text = modele
    cell.labelkmParcourusDepuisAchat?.text = km

    return cell
}
```

I get the carName, which is the field "Pseudo" and I make a query on RealmObject to get the kilométrage array for each car.

I want to retrieve the maximum value of "Kilometrage". This field is defined as String but it is an integer.

Could you please help me to get the maximum value of "kilometrage" using this data ?

```
let consoData = realm.objects(Conso.self).filter("carName = '" + pseudo + "'")
```

I don't know how retrieve data on arrays.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please help me ? :) I am stucked and I can't continue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're going to do Math with a property (mainly on queries), it does not make sense storing it as an `String`.

First, change your property to an Integer:
`@objc dynamic var kilometrage = 0`

Then, [I don't think you can retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804266/how-to-get-item-with-max-id) - through a query - the object with a max value of an **arbitrary property**.

With this in mind, you need to **fetch** **all your objects**, and then **filter** it using `max(by:)`.

```
if let highestKmCar = realm.objects(Car.self).max(by: { $0.kilometrage > $1.kilometrage}) {
    print(highestConsoByKm.kilometrage)
    //Do what you have to do...
}
```